# View behaviour differences between IOS 5.x and IOS 4.x

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, view

I've been trying to animate an image view to slide upwards on the screen. The views height is also increased whilst the position is moved upwards.

On my iPhone 4S (5.x) the image view behaves as expected, the view only moves upwards as its height is increased, however on my iPhone 3G (4.1), the view moves down a little bit during this animation.

Such a level of accuracy is needed as the image view is used to create a non expensive shadow effect. Its alignment is important for the effect. The image is a resizable graphic.

This is how I change the position and size of the view

```
  CGRect oldShadow = self.shaddowView.frame;
  oldShadow.size.height = oldShadow.size.height+200;
  oldShadow.origin.y = oldShadow.origin.y - 200;
  self.shaddowView.frame =oldShadow;
```

This is how the image for the view is set up as resizable:

```
  UIImage* shadow = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"shadow.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:20];
self.shaddowView.image = shadow;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following animation, with a border around not only the starting position but also the intended final position, so that I could confirm whether any undesired shifting of the view (other than the obvious upward expansion) took place, but it worked fine on iOS 4.2.1:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect newImageFrame = imageView.frame;
                     newImageFrame.origin.y -= stretchBy;
                     newImageFrame.size.height += stretchBy;
                     imageView.frame = newImageFrame;
                 }];
```

I don't have iOS 4.1 device sitting around (my old 3G test phone is running iOS 4.2.1, the latest supported iOS version for that device), so I can't speak to that, but it's fine with iOS 4.2.1.

I have to confess, though, that I find it very unlikely that when you animate the changing of a frame, that the final frame would not be precisely what you specified it to be. If you `NSLog` the frame when you're done, it is not the correct value? Or are you saying that it momentarily moves during the animation but then ends up in the correct location? Or that it shifts down during animation and ends up in the wrong position even when the animation is done?

I wonder if there's something else going on (e.g. is your animated view a subview of a scroll view, which itself might be shifting? or is there some code not shown here that is accidentally further adjusting the frame after the animation? etc.). Seems like a little debugging should confirm whether the frame is actually not what you intended, or whether there is some other issue going on.

---

I originally answered suggesting `shouldRasterize` option, but if you're trying to support old iPhone 3G devices, then maybe that's not good enough. Definitely stutters a little on these old phones. Anyway, this was my original answer:

I assume you're doing this because the `layer` shadow feature is a little CPU intensive. But I've heard (but can't speak to it) that if you use the `shouldRasterize` option, it's a little better:

```
viewThatNeedsShadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
viewThatNeedsShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0);
viewThatNeedsShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
viewThatNeedsShadow.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
viewThatNeedsShadow.clipsToBounds = NO;
```